# iPad uitableview off position when rotate landscape and portrait

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I am developing an iPad GUI with 2 uitableview top and bottom, both occupying half the screen with a navigational controller. when i rotate the view, the table does up and hide behind the navigational controller. when launch it doesn't. it only happens when it rotates. Image 1 shows the table when launch. image 2 shows the columns missing when rotating to landscape. image 3 shows the  column missing when shifted back to portrait. is it possible to code a fix position on the screen when portrait and landscape? meaning i set the position when detecting the iPad is in portrait, and landscape.

[image: When app launch. Columns can be seen below the navigation bar.]

[image: after rotate to landscape, the table shifted up. hiding the columns.]

[image: rotate BACK to portrait, the table shifted.]

Answer (score 0):

Override willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: method in your main view controller, and resize your UITableViews by setting their frames.

See also:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: